# Server Error in '/' Application, The resource cannot be found

Tags: c#, asp.net

### Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /public/google_setup.aspx

I am getting the above error when i host the site on the server. In my local computer it is working fine. google_setup.aspx is referring to a master page which is also on the server. I have developed other pages using that master page **before** and they are working fine.

Any idea what is wrong.

If someone can suggest a way to get little bit more detail information on this error i would be able to fix it

Comment: can you hit **any** url on the server?

Comment: Yes all the pages are working. except this one. and the page is there on the server

Comment: If the page would be there you'd get a different kind of error. You're sure about the whole /public thingie?

Comment: Are you certain the file (and subdirectory) are physically on the server where they should be? How did you deploy this app to the server?

Comment: The files are in the server. I published the website then copy the content to the server

Comment: I am not sure what is causing it but my original size had HTTPS settings. The test site I used to test the changes didn’t have https settings. When I removed the security settings all started working.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you are facing a problem with relative and absolute URLs.

Try using the  `~` (tilde) and `runat="server"` when you link to your page:

```
<asp:HyperLink 
    NavigateUrl="~/public/google_setup.aspx"
    runat="server">Google Setup</asp:HyperLink>
```

or

```
<a href="~/public/google_setup.aspx" runat="server">Google Setup</a>
```

Comment: I am not sure what is causing it but my original size had HTTPS settings. The test site I used to test the changes didn’t have https settings. When I removed the security settings all started working.