# .aspx Page is not display after live my website

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-hosting

I'm trying to perform a redirect to another page like this:

```
Response.Redirect("admin1.aspx");
```

the admin1.aspx page is present in that hosting space but i am getting this error..

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.
```

what should i do ...

that admin1.aspx has a master page ...
the hosting server is telling to check my code

[image]

Comment: check you path of admin1.aspx..seems the server cannot find the file

Comment: Try Response.Redirect("~/admin1.aspx");

Comment: the path is ok ... bcoz its in httpdocs

Comment: @IrishChieftain tried it

Comment: Can you show us the directory structure?

Comment: i can give a snapshot but i dont know how to give that here

Comment: You can mimic it in text (just the relevant files) or add an image in the editor.

Comment: did that... i have login.aspx and admin1.aspx under httpdocs ... and web.config and mainmaster.master page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check if the page you are redirecting from (the page you are writing this `Response.Redirect("admin1.aspx");`) and the admin1.aspx are in the same folder.

If they are in the same folder, try accessing the page admin1.aspx directly or any other page in the same folder from the url to make sure the error isn't something else

Check these links as well:

http://forums.iis.net/p/1160687/1916039.aspx

[Server Error in '/' Application, The resource cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758808/server-error-in-application-the-resource-cannot-be-found)

Comment: ok i checked that and it seems like i am unable to view `admin1.aspx` any how... so what can go wrong?? is it in my `admin1.aspx` page?

Comment: can you browse another pages in the same directory?

Comment: yes i an browse to another page

Comment: i mean can you open login.aspx for example?

Comment: yes i can sir but not the admin1.aspx

Comment: then the problem is with this particular page, check page permissions, are you performing url rewrite?

Comment: no i am not doing that ... let me check

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19531/discussion-between-ali-issa-and-drone)